# Over write data in a column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

With the code that I have below I am trying to copy data over to a new sheet but I want it to always start with A2.

I don't want the data to constantly go to the end, I want it to always start in A2. Further more, where the issue comes in is I have formulas in B2:N200 so the data constantly tries to copy to the end.

Originally the code looked like this:

```
if(data[n][0]){
     var dest = ss.getSheetByName(data[n][0].toString().replace(/ /g,''));//find the destination sheet
     Logger.log(data[n][0].toString().replace(/ /g,''))
     var destRange = dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1);// define range
     master.getRange(selectedfirstRow+n,2,1,1).copyTo(destRange);// and make copy below last row
    }
  }
```

And I realized that the Var destRange was defining where to start inputting the data.

```
if(data[n][0]){
     var dest = ss.getSheetByName('Sunday'.replace(/ /g,''));//find the destination sheet
     Logger.log(data[n][0].toString().replace(/ /g,''))
     var destRange = dest.getRange(2+1,1);// define range
     master.getRange(selectedfirstRow+n,2,1,1).copyTo(destRange);// and make copy below last row
    }
  }
```

As you can see I changed the getRange to (2+1,1); It does go to the next row each time I run the function but it only inputs one piece of data rather than consistenly going to the next.

**EDIT**
And I guess I should ask instead, how do I get the last empty cell in the first column only rather than the entire sheet. I know that the code currently is looking at the last row for the whole sheet, how do I get it to just find the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get only the first column of data, and then find the first empty element in the array.

Get a 2D array (Arrays inside of one outer array):

```
//Get the data from the first column only
columnOneData = dest.getRange(1,1,dest.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

That 2D array needs to be collapsed into an 1D array:

```
columnOneData = columnOneData.toString();//Convert the 2D array to a comma seperated string
columnOneData = columnOneData.split(",");//Convert the string to a 1D array
```

Find the first empty element in the new array:

```
firstRowWithEmptyCell = columnOneData.indexOf("") + 1;//Find the first empty element
```

Put together:

```
function test() {
  var columnOneData,data,dest,destRange,firstRowWithEmptyCell,n,selectedfirstRow,ss;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  if(data[n][0]){    
    dest = ss.getSheetByName('Sunday'.replace(/ /g,''));//find the destination sheet
    //Logger.log(data[n][0].toString().replace(/ /g,''))

    columnOneData = dest.getRange(1,1,dest.getLastRow()).getValues();//Get the data from the first column only
    columnOneData = columnOneData.toString();//Convert the 2D array to a comma seperated string
    columnOneData = columnOneData.split(",");//Convert the string to a 1D array

    Logger.log('columnOneData: ' + columnOneData)
    firstRowWithEmptyCell = columnOneData.indexOf("") + 1;//Find the first empty element
    Logger.log('firstRowWithEmptyCell: ' + firstRowWithEmptyCell)

    destRange = dest.getRange(2+1,1);// define range

    master.getRange(selectedfirstRow+n,2,firstRowWithEmptyCell,1).copyTo(destRange);// and make copy below last row
  }
}
```